# Excel Using Structured Reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

Assume a table named: TableA

```
Item     ColA     ColB    ColC       ColD
RowA     10       no      30         40
RW_Start 11       yes     31         41
RowC     12       no      32         42
RW_End   13       yes     33         43
RowE     14       no      34         44
```

I would like to use structured reference as follows:

```
=COUNTIF(TableA[[ColB][RW_End]:[ColB][RW_Start]],"Yes")
```

I tried this versoin:

```
=ROWS(Regions[TableA[[ColB][RW_End]:[ColB][RW_Start]]])
```

and this version:

```
=ROWS(TableA[[ColB][RW_End]:[ColB][RW_Start]])
```

and other permutations, but nothing works throwing a formula error, rather than returning 2 and 3 respectively.

What am I entering wrong?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(TableA[ColB],"Yes")`

Comment: I purposely do not want the entire column, hence my question. I want the if-statement to work across a range of rows.

Comment: `INDEX(TableA[ColB],YourStartRowNumber):INDEX(TableA[ColB],YourEndRowNumber)`  Note that the "Row Numbers" are relative to the range and not the actual row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @Scott Craner, the answer is:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(TableA[ColB],MATCH("RW_End", TableA[Item], 0)):INDEX(TableA[ColB],MATCH("RW_Start", TableA[Item], 0)), "yes")
```